# how to skip lines in pandas dataframe at the end of the xls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
                                                        Energy Supply Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
    Country                                                                                                
    Afghanistan                                          3.210000e+08                       10    78.669280
    Albania                                              1.020000e+08                       35   100.000000
    British Virgin Islands                               2.000000e+06                       85     0.000000
    ...      
    Aruba                                                1.200000e+07                      120    14.870690                                                     ...                      
    Excludes the overseas territories.                            NaN                      NaN          NaN
    Data exclude Hong Kong and Macao Special Admini...            NaN                      NaN          NaN
    Data on kerosene-type jet fuel include aviation...            NaN                      NaN          NaN
    For confidentiality reasons, data on coal and c...            NaN                      NaN          NaN
    Data exclude Greenland and the Danish Faroes.                 NaN                      NaN          NaN
```

I had used `df = pd.read_excel(filelink, skiprows=16)` to cut unwanted information at the very beginning of the file but how can I get rid of the "noize"-information at the end of df?

I had tried to pass a list to skiprows but it messed the results up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need parameter `skip_footer = 5` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **skip_footer** : int, default 0
>
> Rows at the end to skip (0-indexed)

Sample:

```
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', skip_footer = 5)
print (df)
                  Country  Energy Supply  Energy Supply per Capita  \
0             Afghanistan    321000000.0                        10   
1                 Albania    102000000.0                        35   
2  British Virgin Islands      2000000.0                        85   
3                   Aruba     12000000.0                       120   

   % Renewable   
0      78.66928  
1     100.00000  
2       0.00000  
3      14.87069
```

Another solution is remove all rows where all `NaN` in some columns with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')

cols = ['Energy Supply','Energy Supply per Capita','% Renewable']
df = df.dropna(subset=cols, how='all')
print (df)
                  Country  Energy Supply  Energy Supply per Capita  \
0             Afghanistan    321000000.0                      10.0   
1                 Albania    102000000.0                      35.0   
2  British Virgin Islands      2000000.0                      85.0   
3                   Aruba     12000000.0                     120.0   

   % Renewable  
0     78.66928  
1    100.00000  
2      0.00000  
3     14.87069
```